# Implementing simple loading balancing with nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm setting up a web application on Amazon EC2 and using Docker to run multiple containers. I have two approaches in mind, and I'm looking for opinions on which one would be a better fit for my project.

Approach 1: Cloning Project Files into EC2 Instance

I clone my project from a Git repository onto the EC2 instance. and create a image on the ec2 instance.
Then, I create Docker containers running my application on different ports.
I configure load balancing using a configuration file for Nginx.

Approach 2: Using Pre-built Docker Images from Docker Hub

I create Docker images of my application on my local machine and push them to Docker Hub.
On the EC2 instance, I pull these pre-built images to create containers.
I configure load balancing using a configuration file for a load balancer.

I am a beginner so please don't mind if this question is stupid . also I would like to know if any of the above approach is convention or am I doing it completely wrong.

thank you!

Comment: Is Nginx running on the same EC2 instance as the docker images? If so, I would just do the whole thing using docker-compose, including Nginx. Your question about where you should build the image is really irrelevant to the question of load balancing, and honestly where you build and store the docker image is entirely up to your personal preference, it doesn't matter at all.